# Trying to hide/show text field on ViewCont A, from popover(ViewCont B) with table view

Tags: ios, ipad, tableview, popover

there are some variations of this question out there but none seem to help.
I have *two View controller*.

> View Controller (A)  has a text field in it. This text field needs to
>   show/hide depending on the indexPath.row that is selected from a
>   tableView that resides in a popover view (B).

Please help.

in my .h file of the vc where the text field resides:

```
@interface GlobalPageSideDetailViewController : BaseViewController 

<UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *otherTextField;



in .m of where popover (with table view) resides:

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"For table View in popover: %ld", (long)indexPath.row);

    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        //otherTextField.hidden = false;

        //trying to hide/show text field here



    }

}
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you explored using delegate methods?

Comment: yes i have. I created a delegate that the child can call. my parent however is the one that is sending the information over.

Comment: If your parent is sending the information, retain a pointer to the child in -prepareForSegue, and perform a selector on the child.

Comment: Let me know if you're using storyboards or not, and I'll post some sample code.

Comment: yes i am using storyboards

Comment: thanks, i dont have any segues connecting the popover vc to the child vc

Comment: The popover view is the parent?  Please clarify your hierarchy.